# How count how many workers are in leave - mysql

Tags: mysql, date, count, where-clause

Hi everyone in mysql base i have leave table

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------------------
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME | BEGIN_DATE         | END_DATE            | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------+------
| 1      |   4     | LEON    | SPEED |2019-03-20 07:00:00 |2019-03-21 15:00:00  | 
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------------------
```

"Workers Table"

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 4        |  LEON   |  SPEED  |
| 6        |  JACK   |  FAR    |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" Table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order status" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | 
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------
| 30       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|
| 31       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-19 06:44:35  |2019-03-19 15:13:32|
| 32       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:45:33  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|
| 33       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-21 06:50:01  |2019-03-21 15:20:44|
| 34       |   4     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|
| 35       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|
| 36       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-19 06:55:32  |2019-03-19 15:33:45|
| 37       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|
| 38       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-21 06:53:23  |2019-03-21 15:11:44|
| 39       |   6     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+------------------+
```

What i'd like to do?

I want count **how many workers are in leave in specified date** for example for 20-03-2019 is only 1 worker on leave. i've tried with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(leave.ID_WORKER) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE' 
FROM leave
INNER JOIN order_status
ON order_status.ID_WORKER = leave.ID_WORKER 
INNER JOIN orders
WHERE DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '2019-03-20' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) ='2019-03-20' AND orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST'
```

then i have :

```
NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 1
```

for 2019-03-21 i get:

```
 NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 0
```

But for 2019-03-19 i've got:

```
 NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 1
```

Why does it like that in 2019-03-21 NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE should be 1 and in 2019-03-19 should be 0. Where should i change that which it would work. Thank you for any advice and help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to make sure that what your query does return the result you wanted. Let's do some checking first.

Here I extract your first `INNER JOIN` and change to `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT * FROM leave
INNER JOIN order_status
ON order_status.ID_WORKER = leave.ID_WORKER;
```

This is the result I get when executing the query above.
[image: Result 1]

Then I add the third join;

```
SELECT * FROM leave
INNER JOIN order_status
ON order_status.ID_WORKER = leave.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders;
```

This will add three extra columns from `orders` table. Refer photo below:
[image: Result 2]

NOTE: Your second `INNER JOIN` doesn't have `ON` condition. I recommend that you fix that part by adding `ON order_status.ID_ORDER=orders.ID_ORDER`.

So far all the results are giving 5 rows. These 5 rows are coming from your `order_status` table and since you're joining `leave` table using relation of `ID_WORKER`, it will return all that matches with that field.

Now we test your query with the first `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(leave.ID_WORKER) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE' 
FROM leave
INNER JOIN order_status
ON order_status.ID_WORKER = leave.ID_WORKER 
INNER JOIN orders ON order_status.ID_ORDER=orders.ID_ORDER -- (I've added this condition)
WHERE DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '2019-03-20';
```

This `WHERE` condition here doesn't work because you take `BEGIN_DATE` from `order_status` table. If you inspect your `order_status` table, `ID_WORKER=4` have data for all the dates from 2019-03-19 to 2019-03-21. This means that whatever date you put in, you'll always get `NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 1` result.

I have tested your query with your example data and I get `NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 1` on all of the dates. I'm not sure how did you get `NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE = 0` on the `2019-03-21`.

So, after doing all that, I manage to do this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(leave.ID_WORKER) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS IN LEAVE'
FROM leave
INNER JOIN order_status
ON order_status.ID_WORKER = leave.ID_WORKER 
AND DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) BETWEEN DATE(leave.BEGIN_DATE) AND DATE(leave.END_DATE) -- this condition added
INNER JOIN orders ON order_status.ID_ORDER=orders.ID_ORDER
WHERE DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '2019-03-21' 
AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) ='2019-03-21' 
AND orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';
```

What I did on the query is I've added another condition is your first `JOIN`. This will return the result you desired.
However, due to limited data, I'm not sure if the query above will be useful for the long run. If it does, then it's a good thing. But if doesn't, please feedback to me of what other condition(s) you would like to add in the query.